# Get the data of an HTML form in Java

Tags: java, html, forms, get, jlabel

I have a problem in Java using JLabel.

I generated a form in HTML in a JLabel but I don't know how to get the values when the user clicks on "Validate" and the PHP does not work.

How can I do this?

Extract of code:

```
**String s="<html><head>";

  s+="<style>table{border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;} td{border: 1px solid black;}";

  s+="i{background-color:red; color:white;}";
  s+="b{background-color:blue; color:silver;}";

  s+="</style>";
  s+="</head><body><form><h1>Formulaire généré N°1</h1>"; 
  s+="<br /><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Envoyer'>"; // Here is the problem
  s+=" <INPUT TYPE='reset' VALUE='Reset'>";       
  s+="</form></body></html>";**
```

Comment: `JLabel` is a Swing UI component. Why would you create an HTML document inside the label? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What "does not work" and where is this connected to PHP?

Comment: You should not use a JLabel. Rather, use a Dialog. The easy one would be JOptionPane. showInputDialog.